# any way to manually set the "Script Name" when adding JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, itext

I use iText to batch enable shared reviews in pdf files at the server level.  Injecting the required javascript is accomplished using the PdfStamper's addJavascript() function.  This does enable the shared review, however i cannot create archive versions properly because the document level javascript "Script Name" is not correct.  iText sets the Script Name sequentially starting with 0000000000000000, then 0000000000000001, etc.  I need to set the Script Name to "com.adobe.acrobat.SharedReview.Register" instead.  Is there any reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Are you sure you removed the right tag? iText is a Java library and (as the question points out) is being called from the server. This question would certainly seem to involve a Java-oriented answer. Perhaps the JavaScript tag should be removed instead?

Comment: @neuronaut: now I'm not so sure... one reason I like to leave comments when changing tags. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll re-add the [tag:java].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check the iText source code myself, and to my surprise I discovered that we overlooked a method. There was supposed to be a method that allows you to choose the name, but there isn't.

You can work around this by adding the JavaScript straight to the writer:

```
stamper.getWriter().addJavaScript(
    "com.adobe.acrobat.SharedReview.Register",
    PdfAction.javaScript(js, stamper.getWriter(), !PdfEncodings.isPdfDocEncoding(js)));
```

where `js` is the JavaScript you want to add.

Granted, this isn't elegant. Let me know if this works, and I'll see if I can add the extra method in one of the next releases.

Comment: Thanks Bruno!  That worked like a charm, I just had to add an extra () to getWriter.  This worked for me:

Comment: Thanks Bruno!  That worked like a charm, I just had to add an extra () to getWriter.  This worked for me:
stamper.getWriter().addJavaScript("com.adobe.acrobat.SharedReview.Register", PdfAction.javaScript(js, stamper.getWriter(), !PdfEncodings.isPdfDocEncoding(js)));

Comment: The missing () was a typo. I've fixed it.